# How to attach a drawer without screwing?

Tags: wooden-furniture, drawers, rental

In my rented flat, I have a kitchen table that has a gap beneath it with another surface underneath, as shown in the picture (*it is open on both sides*)

I would like to put a drawer in this gap for cutlery etc. (*it is about 80 cm wide, 60 cm deep and 10 cm high*).

While an option is to screw drawer runners on both sides, I unfortunately cannot do that because I can't damage the table.

Is there any alternative to insert a drawer, other than just laying it in the gap.

[image: Drawer slot]

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

Make a box that is about the size of the space.  The front should fit fairly close.  The box itself should have about 1/4" spacing all around it.  That's 1/2" narrower than the opening and 1/2 shorter than the opening is tall.

On the back side pieces put felt furniture glides top and bottom. On the front put them on the bottom of the space.

In use the front of the drawer rides on the felts at the front of the space.  The back of the drawer rides on either set of felts depending on the combination of upward force (most of us lift a drawer while pulling it) and the amount of drawer in the space.

When you move, set a hot water bottle on the felt for 20 minutes.  It should peel off easily.  If there is adhesive residue try goo-gone, or mineral spirits.

The glides I'm referring to are 1/8 to 3/16" thick made of beige felt.  One side is adhesive with a protective paper on it.